# usando javascript como pasar una variable con un window.open a una vista usando laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

tengo una función que hace una petición ajax y la petición funciona correctamente, pero cuando realiza el success quiero que un `window.open` me redirija hacia otra pantalla. el `window.open` que tengo implementado es el siguiente:

`window.open( '{{ route('reportes.InformePDFEspecialista') }}', '_blank');`

Ahora, este `window.open` va a ir a una vista a la cual tengo que pasarle una variables que obtuve de la petición `ajax`. Mi pregunta es como puedo pasarle esas variables usando el `window.open`

Comment: Intentaste esto window.open( '{{ route('reportes.InformePDFEspecialista','Dato') }}', '_blank');. recuerda que la ruta debe estar definida con el parámetro de entrada.

Comment: Por qué no utilizas ajax para redireccionar?

Comment: pero como le paso ese Dato que es una variable que me devuelve el controller en la peticion

Comment: y como le paso el datos en la redireccion de ajax

Comment: Comparte el código de la función completo para poder analizar su caso.

Comment: Supongo que devuelves un JSON como respuesta en AJAX y podrías agregar una propiedad `redir` con la ruta de la página que se debe abrir.